# Internal Server Error - Is it my syntax?

Tags: php, syntax

I've just wrote out this slab of PHP. I get an internal server error when I run it, however. Is it a syntax error? Would anyone mind looking over it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
echo error_reporting(E_ALL);
$p1MON = strval($_GET['p1MON']);
$p1TUE = strval($_GET['p1TUE']);
$p1WED = strval($_GET['p1WED']);
$p1THU = strval($_GET['p1THU']);
$p1FRI = strval($_GET['p1FRI']);

$p2MON = strval($_GET['p2MON']);
$p2TUE = strval($_GET['p2TUE']);
$p2WED = strval($_GET['p2WED']);
$p2THU = strval($_GET['p2THU']);
$p2FRI = strval($_GET['p2FRI']);

$p3MON = strval($_GET['p3MON']);
$p3TUE = strval($_GET['p3TUE']);
$p3WED = strval($_GET['p3WED']);
$p3THU = strval($_GET['p3THU']);
$p3FRI = strval($_GET['p3FRI']);

$p4MON = strval($_GET['p4MON']);
$p4TUE = strval($_GET['p4TUE']);
$p4WED = strval($_GET['p4WED']);
$p4THU = strval($_GET['p4THU']);
$p4FRI = strval($_GET['p4FRI']);

$p5MON = strval($_GET['p5MON']);
$p5TUE = strval($_GET['p5TUE']);
$p5WED = strval($_GET['p5WED']);
$p5THU = strval($_GET['p5THU']);
$p5FRI = strval($_GET['p5FRI']);

$p6MON = strval($_GET['p6MON']);
$p6TUE = strval($_GET['p6TUE']);
$p6WED = strval($_GET['p6WED']);
$p6THU = strval($_GET['p6THU']);
$p6FRI = strval($_GET['p6FRI']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','XXXX','XXXX','XXXX');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
} else {

$sql = "INSERT INTO Caspar (day, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6)
VALUES ('MON', '$p1MON', '$p2MON', '$p3MON', '$p4MON', '$p5MON', '$p6MON')";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo "okay";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
    }
mysqli_close($con);
}
?></body>
</html>
```

Thank you. If you find anything, or would like any more information, please let me know.

Comment: You need to turn error reporting on to recieve the actual *error*. You can do it like this in `php` code: `error_reporting(1);`

Comment: I already had error reporting set on E_ALL @Nytrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, no need to use `echo` before `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
then your last curly bracket is invalid, remove it and try again. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, that hit the nail on the head. Works great.